# How to install Gitlab CI and Runner in VPS like GCE

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, google-compute-engine

Seeking for advice about how to setup git CI(continuous integration like gitlab CI) in VPS like Google Compute Engine. As companies like Digital Ocean and Cloud Pipe have similar solutions, I guess there must be a kind of process of how-to, especially for Google Compute Engine.

Any advice is quite appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I found Google Compute Engine provides Gitlab installation option when creating an instance VM.